# Show that for every $\epsilon>0$ and every closed ball $K\subset X$ there is an $N$ such that $||T_nx-Tx||<\epsilon$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T_n\to T$, where $T_n\in B(X,Y)$. Show that for every $\epsilon>0$ and every closed ball $K\subset X$ there is an $N$ such that $||T_nx-Tx||<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$ and all $x\in K$.

I don't know how to start this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would it help if $K = \overline{B}(0,1)$? Next: Is the closed ball bounded?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Should the closed ball be bounded? Or are you just asking for clarification?

Comment: Suppose you know that $\|x\| \le 1$. Can you prove the result then?

Comment: I don't follow.

Comment: How do you define $\|T-T_n\|$? Note that $\|Tx-T_nx\| \le \|T-T_n\| \|x\|$.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @copper.hat I am not able to solve this. Kindly provide some more hints.

Comment: @cabmetric Since $K$ is bounded, there is some $M$ such that $\|x\| \le M$ for any $x \n K$. Now combine this with my last comment.